# Protobuf-net Exception with Unknown Subclasses

Tags: c#, exception, protobuf-net

I have developed an application that is meant to send data from client to server and back etc. using serialized objects.

For this application, I decided that protobuf-net would be a good option (especially as it handles variable-length objects so well).

However, when sending an object from client to server or vica-versa, all I know is that the object will be some child class of 'ReplicableObject'. Hence, I am using:

```
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, ro, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

Where 'ro' is an object of a type that subclasses from ReplicableObject.

However, I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' occurred in
>   protobuf-net.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected type found during serialization;
>   types must be included with ProtoIncludeAttribute; found MessageObject
>   passed as ReplicableObject

In this particular instance, I'm trying to send a *MessageObject*.

As there is precious little documentation for protobuf-net, I am stuck on what to do. I've tried a few attributes here and there to no avail.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: I should make it clear that the subclasses might not even be ones that I've written.

Comment: I've just returned from a few days away. I will look at this later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf is a contract-based serialization format, designed to be platform independent. As such, *no* type metadata is included on the wire as it would not apply between platforms. Even inheritance is not part of the core protobuf spec.

protobuf-net as a *specific implementation* introduces support for inheritance (via some smoke and mirrors), but ideally it should still be possible to define the expected types in advance - exactly the same as other serializers such as `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`. This can be done by using `[ProtoInclude(...)]` to specify the anticipated concrete types.

If you genuinely can't tell the actual types in advance, there is also a `DynamicType` option, which writes the AssemblyQualifiedName into the stream. If you are interested in this route, then note that the "cross-platform" features of the format start to break down, but it is very useful for .NET-to-.NET purposes.

At the simplest, a wrapper such as:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeWrapper {
     [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
     public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

Wrap your object in *that* and it should behave (in v2 at least; DynamicType did not exist in v1). Full example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SO7218127
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var orig = new SomeWrapper {Value = new SubType { Foo = 123, Bar = "abc"}};
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(orig);
        Assert.AreEqual(123, orig.Value.Foo);
        Assert.AreEqual("abc", ((SubType) clone.Value).Bar);
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SomeWrapper
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public BaseType Value { get; set; }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class BaseType
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SubType : BaseType
    {
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```